# PHPSpreadsheet formula not working between dates

Tags: php, excel, datetime, phpspreadsheet

I want to calculate difference between 2 datetimes in hours with PHPSpreadsheet. This is how Excel does it:

[image]

A1 and A2 cells format is:

[image]

This is the result on web:

[image]

When I change value through PHPSpreadsheet, I get #VALUE! and different value formatting.

```
$reader = PhpSpreadsheet\IOFactory::createReader("Xlsx");
$target_file = __DIR__ . '/test.xlsx';
$spreadsheet = $reader->load($target_file);
$spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('A1', '24.6.2020 12:30');
$writer = new PhpSpreadsheet\Writer\Html($spreadsheet);
$output = $writer->generateHTMLHeader();
$output .= $writer->generateStyles(true);
$output .= $writer->generateSheetData();
$output .= $writer->generateHTMLFooter();
$doc = new DOMDocument();
@$doc->loadHTML($output);
echo $doc->saveHTML();
```

[image]

I also tried with formatting like this 6/24/2020 14:30 but the result was same (#VALUE!)

```
$spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('A1', '6/24/2020 14:30');
```

Anyone got any idea on how this should be done?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In an Excel document, dates are stored as numbers, not strings. So you need to pass the correct number to `setCellValue()`.

PhpSpreadsheet provides the utility method [`Date::stringToExcel()`](https://phpoffice.github.io/PhpSpreadsheet/classes/PhpOffice-PhpSpreadsheet-Shared-Date.html#method_stringToExcel) to convert strings to Excel dates. You can use it like this:

```
$date = PhpSpreadsheet\Shared\Date::stringToExcel('2020-06-24 12:30');
$spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('A1', $date);
```

Comment: @wast You can use any formatting to display the date. `stringToExcel()` has nothing to do with formatting, it just computes the internal number value.

Comment: @Oliver I didnt know about this function and it will certainly help me in my day job. Thanks!

Comment: @Olivier OK but how does the function know how to parse the string if it's not the default format?

Comment: @wast `stringToExcel()` expects the string with the format YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI.